# Function using conditions

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a function that considers a determined number of samples (rivers) each one with a determined number of observations. Given 10 samples each one with 12 observations in a lognormal distribution with mean=4 and sd=1.4, I would like to obtain the number of times a particular number (6 - it refers to a standard number for water quality measurement) is counted.
The following is the code for one experiment, considering "limit" as the maximum number of observations allowed to ovverpass 6.

```
set.seed(1001)
nobs<-12
limit<-round(0.10 * nobs, digits = 0) 
h2o <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*12, mean = 4, sd = 1.4), ncol = 12))
paste(rep("Riv", nrow(h2o)), c(1:nrow(h2o)), sep = "")
rownames(h2o) <- paste(rep("Riv", nrow(h2o)), c(1:nrow(h2o)), sep = "")
colnames(h2o) <- paste(rep("Obs", ncol(h2o)), c(1:ncol(h2o)), sep = "")
```

#Number of rivers declared impared based in the assumptiom that the number of observations per river are 2 or more?

```
ifelse(h2o >=6,1,0)
h2o$Test<-rowSums(ifelse(h2o >=6,1,0))
length(h2o$Test[h2o$Test>1])
```

The function should resume the previous data and works for different observations with different samples.

Thanks

Comment: Please, can you specify which parameters you want to pass to the function and what the expected return is?

Comment: My paramenters are number of rivers in a sequence of `r<-c(10,50,100,500)` from which I obtain 10, 50, 100 and 500 samples to assess water quality.

Comment: My paramenters are # of rivers in a sequence of `r<-c(10,50,100,500)` from which I obtain 10, 50, 100 and 500 samples to assess water quality. I expect to obtain a simulation of the # of rivers with values higher than the standard limit referred to 6. Thus, for 10 samples in 10 rivers, I know there is 20% of samples over 6. Now, I want to have not only the value of 10 by 10 but also the value up to 10 by 500 and 500 by 10 up to 500 by 500. I have this loop `vec<-seq(10,500,by=10)
for(i in vec) { res<-Test(y=i,x=10)
  results[i]<-res
  results10<-results[!is.na(results)]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function using `dplyr` and `tidyr` from the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_h2o <- function(data, threshold_quality = 6, limit = 1) {
  table <- data %>%
  rownames_to_column("river") %>%
  gather(observation, value, -river) %>%
    mutate(over_lim = value > threshold_quality)

  table_wide <- table %>%
    select(river, observation, over_lim) %>%
    mutate(over_lim = over_lim %>% as.integer()) %>%
    spread(observation, over_lim)

  summary <- table %>%
    group_by(river) %>%
    summarize(over_lim_count = sum(over_lim))

  result <- summary %>%
    summarize(num_impaired = sum(over_lim_count > limit))

  list(table_wide, summary, result)
}
```

Here's the output, meant to show the steps in your example:

```
> test_h2o(h2o)
[[1]]
   river Obs1 Obs10 Obs11 Obs12 Obs2 Obs3 Obs4 Obs5 Obs6 Obs7 Obs8 Obs9
1   Riv1    0     0     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2  Riv10    0     0     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3   Riv2    0     0     1     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4   Riv3    1     0     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
5   Riv4    0     0     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
6   Riv5    0     1     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
7   Riv6    0     1     1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
8   Riv7    0     0     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
9   Riv8    0     0     0     0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
10  Riv9    1     0     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   river over_lim_count
   <chr>          <int>
 1 Riv1               0
 2 Riv10              0
 3 Riv2               1
 4 Riv3               1
 5 Riv4               1
 6 Riv5               1
 7 Riv6               3
 8 Riv7               0
 9 Riv8               2
10 Riv9               1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  num_impaired
         <int>
1            2
```

Comment: Looks amazing Jon. I was thinking in using something more simple like this:     
`Test <- function(x,y) {
  n <- length(x)
  nobs<- y
  limit<-round(0.10 * y, digits = 0)
  h2o <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n*y, mean=4, sd=1.4), ncol= y))
  h2o$Test <- rowSums(ifelse(h2o>6, 1, 0))
  length(h2o$Test[h2o$Test>limit])/y
  return(h2o$Test)
}
Test(10,100)`,   for 10 rivers and 100 observations. There is clealyr something wrong with this code.